# How to pass POST variables with javascript targeting a new tab into an online compiler just like html-form does?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xmlhttprequest, interpreter

I want a link "Run this in " just below each PRE-CODE block.

The link should popup a new tab with any online compiler/interpreter and the code of the block.

*I don't know if there is a solution already done. Like highlight.js but do this. So I tried my own approach **unsuccessfully**. I want to keep the HTML simple and clean.*

Picked jdoodle as starting point, but the idea is to have options.
The HTML form, works! Either by redirecting or by changing the target to a new tab.

Now I want this working without the HTML FORM (to keep the HTML simple and clean) and do this in a javascript function call.

With XMLHttpRequest to perform the POST call, I get errors on CORS policy.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.jdoodle.com/api/redirect-to-post/execute-lua-online/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I believe that this doesn't happens with HTML-FORM because it redirects and origin gets to be the same.

**So I tried unsuccessfully to either use XMLHttpRequest to redirect or popup into jdoodle but I cant get to transfer the POST data containing the code.**

#### My non-working-javascript-example

```
<pre><code class="language-lua">
print("hello jdoodle")
</code></pre>
<a href="#" onclick="runthis(this); return false;">Run this on jDoodle.</a>
```

```
<form id="inputform" method="post" action=
"https://www.jdoodle.com/api/redirect-to-post/execute-lua-online/" target="_blank">
    <textarea name="initScript" 
        rows="4" cols="20">
print("Either redirecting or in a tab, it works!")
    </textarea>
      <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Test">
</form>
```

```
<script>
function runthis(caller) {
    prev_el = caller.previousElementSibling;
    code_el = prev_el.getElementsByTagName("CODE")[0];
    code_str = code_el.innerText;
    alert(code_str);
    
    var handle=window.open("https://www.jdoodle.com/api/redirect-to-post/execute-lua-online/");

    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    http.open('POST', 'https://www.jdoodle.com/api/redirect-to-post/execute-lua-online/', true);

    http.onload = function () {
      console.log(this.responseText); 
      };
      
    FD = new FormData();
    FD.append('initScript', code_str);
    FD.append('submit', 'Test');
    alert(JSON.stringify(FD)); // it shows empty ¿why?

    http.send(FD);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but I would always appreciate better alternatives.

As the HTML Form was working, the first step is to reproduce this in javascript, and this is not done with XMLHttpRequest.

```
function runthis_on_external_site(pre_elem, url, textareaname="initScript" ) {
    code_el = pre_elem.getElementsByTagName("CODE")[0];
    code_str = code_el.innerText;

    var form_elem = document.createElement("FORM");
    form_elem.method = "POST";
    form_elem.action = url;
    form_elem.target = "_blank";

    var element1 = document.createElement("TEXTAREA"); 
    element1.name=textareaname;
    element1.innerHTML = code_str;
    form_elem.appendChild(element1);  

    document.body.appendChild(form_elem);
    form_elem.submit();
    form_elem.remove();
}
```

Then a link must be added below each `<PRE><CODE>` block after the page is loaded.

```
function insert_A_tag_after_( pre_elem, inner, url, textareaname) {
  A = document.createElement("A");
  A.className = 'ref';
  A.href = '#';
  A.innerHTML = inner;
  A.onclick = function() { 
        runthis_on_external_site( pre_elem, url, textareaname); 
        };
  pre_elem.parentNode.insertBefore(A, pre_elem.nextSibling);
}

//========================================================
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log('Adding external Compilers/Interpreters');
    document.querySelectorAll( 'code' ).forEach((e) => {
    
    if( e.classList.contains( 'language-lua' ) ){
        url = "https://www.jdoodle.com/api/redirect-to-post/execute-lua-online/";
        insert_A_tag_after_( e.parentNode, "jDoodle", url, "initScript" );
        url = "https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo";
        insert_A_tag_after_( e.parentNode, "lua.org", url, "input" );
        
    }
        
    })
});
```

- NOTE: that, I have only found jDoodle and lua.org/cgi-bin/demo so far to be able to get the code from a POST variable. Others online compilers would be appreciated.
- NOTE2: I picked the class name as 'language-lua' for compatibility with highlight.js
- NOTE3: As far as I could research, I couldn't found any other popular alternative solution for this. Most solutions are to embed a compiler/editor from only one site.